# How can I remove a Darksteel Citadel animated by Nissa, Worldwaker?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

After the coming rotation with Khans of Tarkir being released, will there be any way to remove from the battlefield a [Darksteel Citadel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darksteel%20Citadel) that has been turned into a creature by [Nissa, Worldwaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nissa%2C%20Worldwaker)'s first +1 ability?

It seems the me that being indestructible and also a land protect it from almost all removal, [Devour Flesh](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Devour%20Flesh) in the current standard being the only obvious exception.

I'm looking for solutions in the soon-to-be Theros + Khans of Tarkir standard format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any card that says "Exile target creature", "Exile target artifact", or "Exile target permanent" will remove an animated Darksteel Citadel. Cards that do this include

- [Devouring Light](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Devouring%20Light)
- [Pillar of Light](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pillar%20of%20Light)
- [Ashen Rider](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashen%20Rider)
- [Chained to the Rocks](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chained%20to%20the%20Rocks)
- [Curse of the Swine](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Curse%20of%20the%20Swine)
- [Excoriate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Excoriate)
- [Fade Into Antiquity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fade%20Into%20Antiquity)
- [Gild](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gild)

In addition, if it's toughness ever drops to 0, it will die as a state based effect. [Lash of the Whip](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lash%20of%20the%20Whip), for example, will kill it.

Comment: I was hopeing for specific examples from the soon to be Standard format. Thanks though.

Comment: Done. There are a lot more. I just got bored of listing them.

Comment: Gatherer's got you covered: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&format=[%22Standard%22]&text=|[%22EXILE%20ALL%22]|[%22EXILE%20ANY%22]|[%22EXILE%20TARGET%22]

Comment: Also from Khans: Dead Drop.

Comment: I didn't know that you could search for Standard. That's great. But note that that search is currently incorrect (it still shows pre-rotation cards), and that it misses cards like Curse of the Swine and Perilous Vault.

Comment: Murgatroid: Fixed for Perilous Vault, and for Standard, we'll just have to give it time... :-)

Comment: Fixed link, excludes RTR & M14, handles the Swine Curse Edge Case. Unfortunately Gatherer doesn't handle exclusions well when something is in both a current and old block. http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&format=[%22Standard%22]&text=|[%22EXILE%20ALL%22]|[%22EXILE%20ANY%22]|[%22EXILE%20TARGET%22]|[%22Exile%20X%22]&block=+![%22Return%20to%20Ravnica%22]&set=+![%222014%22]

Comment: Or you could just use this: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&format=[%22Standard%22]&block=+![%22Return%20to%20Ravnica%22]&set=+![%222014%22]&text=+[exile].

Comment: @murgatroid99 See "Beckon Apparition", because it's from Eventide as well as Gatecrash the query doesn't exclude it. Also, "Exile" on its own picks up stuff like Act on Impulse. #

Comment: No search for this is going to be perfect. Both of ours include stuff like "Exile target non-land...". And the important thing is that the asker knows now what to search for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17217/discussion-between-deworde-and-murgatroid99).

Answer (score 4):

Apart from Exile Effects; the Other things that can deal with indestructible creature-lands:

- -X/-X abilities like [Nightmarish End](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nightmarish%20End), [Lash of the Whip](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lash%20of%20the%20Whip)
- Sacrifice abilities like [Dead Drop](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dead%20Drop)
- Bounce effects like [Whelming Wave](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Whelming%20Wave), [Peel from Reality](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Peel%20from%20Reality), and [Aetherspouts](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aetherspouts)
- Polymorph effects like [Turn to Frog](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Turn%20to%20Frog) and [Polymorphist's Jest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Polymorphist%27s%20Jest) (although I think you'll have to kill the frog before ToF wears off).

Comment: Retraction Helix does not deal with indestructible lands ;)

Comment: @Affe Whups, Fixed.